# Renovating transcendental idealism

Tags: history-of-philosophy, kant

In the 20th century, philosophers such as P.F Strawson and Paul Guyer attempted to disentangle (what they viewed as) the unsavory components of Kant's system of transcendental idealism from (what they viewed as) Kant's contributions to philosophy that are worth preserving. I unfortunately do not have time to read either of these philosophers' books over the summer, and so I wanted to ask if anyone could share with me the names of any academic papers which discuss and evaluate how successful philosophers like Strawson and Guyer were at their attempts to thresh transcendental idealism.

Answer (score 4):

Allison is known for criticizing Strawson's reading of Kant's transcendental idealism according to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_idealism):

> In Kant's Transcendental Idealism, Henry E. Allison proposes a reading that opposes Strawson's interpretation. Allison argues that Strawson and others misrepresent Kant by emphasising what has become known as the two-worlds reading (a view developed by Paul Guyer). This—according to Allison, false—reading of Kant's phenomena/noumena distinction suggests that phenomena and noumena are ontologically distinct from each other. It concludes on that basis that we somehow fall short of knowing the noumena due to the nature of the very means by which we comprehend them. On such a reading, Kant would himself commit the very fallacies he attributes to the transcendental realists. On Allison's reading, Kant's view is better characterized as a two-aspect theory, where noumena and phenomena refer to complementary ways of considering an object. It is the dialectic character of knowing, rather than epistemological insufficiency, that Kant wanted most to assert.

You can access Allison's book *Kant's Transcendental Idealism: An Interpretation and Defense* [here](http://www.pazeinat.com/einat_family/Philosophy/Allison,%20Henry%20-%20Kant%27s%20Transcendental%20Idealism;%20An%20Interpretation%20and%20Defense.pdf). And there's even a book review of Allison's defense by Sebastian Gardner as referenced [here](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/kant-s-transcendental-idealism-an-interpretation-and-defense-revised-and-enlarged-edition/):

> As he affirms, the landscape has changed considerably since 1983. Whereas originally Allison introduced his interpretation of transcendental idealism by means of relatively few contrasts, principally H. A. Prichard and Strawson, the present horizon of Kantian studies includes also, among others, Paul Guyer, Rae Langton, and Karl Ameriks, all of whom have criticised Allison and formulated opposing positions on the nature of transcendental idealism. Allison intends his revised interpretation of transcendental idealism also to counter what he believes to be the increased Strawsonian tendency to regard Kant's transcendental idealism as separable from the other main components of his theoretical philosophy.